# How to access native methods with a jQuery selector?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors, html5-audio

I have the following :

```
<audio src="blah.mp3" id="player" controls></audio>
```

`document.getElementById('player').play();` **works**.
`$('audio#player').play();` **don't**.

Why ? Can't I access native methods with a jQuery selector ?

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/get/

Comment: I think you mean a jQuery object, the string you pass as the parameter is the selector. To get the underlying object, you can just access it in the array: `$('#player')[0].play()`. Thirdly, there can only be one element with any ID on a page, no need to overspecify by adding the tag type to the selector as well as the ID.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since jQuery will *wrap* queried DOM Elements into *Array-like-Objects*, you need to access them via index. For instance

```
$('audio#player')[0].play();
```

Since we query via *Id* here, we can be sure that there is precisely one *Element* in our wrapped set so we can just get it with `[0]` (alternatively, you can use jQuery's very own [`.get()`](http://api.jquery.com/get/) method to receive the *Node*).

Comment: Additionally, if you use the `.get()` method, you can use negative indexes, for example `-1` for the last object in the 'array'.